# Sequence of tenses: is it optional if I have the exact time in the clause?

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

> He said he had done it the week before.
>
> He said he did it last week.

Are they correct and mean exactly the same?

My textbook says that the following two are identical in meaning:

> He said that he went to the theater yesterday.
>
> He said that he had gone to the theater the day before.

Does this work with the phrase *last week*?

Answer (score 2):

The two similar sentences are not necessarily identical in meaning.

To say **last week** or **yesterday** are specified periods of time. **Last week** is the week before the current week. **Yesterday** is the day before today.

But both **the week before** and **the day before** prompt the question: **Before what?**

**The week/day before** could refer to the week/day before Christmas. So unless you are able to determine the time from the context, you cannot be sure which day or week is being referred to.

Comment: Would these be correct then? When I met him *this morning* he told me that he went to the movies yesterday. When I met him [the time is not specified] he told me that he had gone to the movies the day before.

Comment: The first is fine and specific. The second again prompts the question **Before what?** You might have met him a month earlier.

Comment: "I was in Paris last month. When I met him there he told me that he had gone to the new movie theater the day before." Now I have specified the moment: last month. Would this be considered correct?

Comment: Or rather, he had been at the movie theater the day before I met him in Paris last month.

Comment: Yes, they make it clear that he said he had been / went to the movie theatre the day before you met him in Paris last month.